# "dpkg: warning: missing file from the list of files" Everything is missing

Tags: dpkg

I asked someone to install some basic stuff in an Ubuntu 20.04.3 server. I'm not an expert, but I know this is a fairly easy task to do, even for someone with little experience dealing with a server.

They successfully installed a couple of the programs needed, but then went back to me telling me that they had trouble installing Apache, which is odd given how straightforward this installation is.

Anyway, I looked into this and was greeted by the warning in the title no matter what I installed/removed.

A lot of the answers online pretty much say to either reinstall the 'missing' packages or to clean apt/dpkg. I tried the latter, since the list of missing package "seemed too long". A couple hours and tries later, I tried reinstalling one of the packages, and it stopped showing up in this warnings.

I settled in reinstalling what it asked me to, so a lot of grep later I ended up with a list of the missing packages.

It's pretty much the entire Operating System, including working programs such as `mysql-server` and `openssh`, all the way to `login`, `apt` and `grub2-common`, to desktop packages like `nautilus` and `libre-office`. Yes, this is a server. No, I didn't install those.

This tells me there is something very wrong here, but again, I'm fairly new to Linux/Unix altogether to draw this conclusion.

Should I just `--reinstall` everything in the list or should I try to get deeper into this? The installation is pretty new (It was done February 18th) so I can still just clean the disk and start over. I honestly don't think the person I asked to install stuff could do this. This seems... too deliberate, somehow.

EDIT:

I looked into the list. There are some non-programs in it too. They are /var/lib/dpkg/info/format-new and /var/lib/dpkg/status. I'll try to look for this one particulary in the logs.

Also, in the apt log, I don't see anything pointing me to the package that started this issue, nor a package with GUI. I now know that they tried to install a desktop environment, but don't know how (The basic/core gnome package is not installed, but I see a lot of gnome packages).

EDIT 2:

From `/var/log/apt/term.log`, I'm interested in every line like the following (original line and an approximate translation)

```
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `login', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
```

(dpkg: warning: Missing file from the list of files `login', it will be supposed that the package currently has no installed files)

This is the list of files (some `a`s and `m`s are missing).

```
ccountsservice
cl
cpi
cpi-support
user
wit-icon-thee
isleriot
ls-bse
ls-topology-conf
ls-uc-conf
ls-utils
-icrocoe
ncron
pche2
pche2-bin
pche2-t
pche2-utils
pg
ppror
pp-instll-t-prtner
pport
pport-gtk
pport-syptos
ppstre
pt
pt-config-icons
pt-config-icons-hipi
pteon
pteon-t
pturl
pturl-coon
pt-utils
spell
spell-en
t
t-spi2-core
ttr
vhi-utoip
vhi-eon
vhi-utils
bobb
bse-files
bse-pssw
bsh
bsh-copletion
bc
bcche-tools
bin9-nsutils
bin9-host
bin9-libs
bluez
bluez-cups
bluez-obex
bolt
brning-ubuntu
brltty
bsinutils
bsutils
btrfs-progs
bubblewrp
busybox-initrfs
busybox-sttic
byobu
bzip2
c-certifictes
c-certifictes-jv
cheese
cheese-coon
cifs-utils
clou-guest-utils
clou-init
clou-initrfs-copyos
clou-initrfs-yn-netconf
color
color-t
con-not-foun
console-setup
console-setup-linux
coreutils
cpio
cpp
cpp-9
crcklib-runtie
cr
cron
cryptsetup
cryptsetup-bin
cryptsetup-initrfs
cryptsetup-run
cups
cups-browse
cups-bs
cups-client
cups-coon
cups-core-rivers
cups-eon
cups-filters
cups-filters-core-rivers
cups-ipp-utils
cups-pk-helper
cups-ppc
cups-server-coon
curl
sh
bus
bus-user-session
bus-x11
c
conf-cli
conf-gsettings-bcken
conf-service
ebconf
ebconf-i18n
ebinutils
ej-up
esktop-file-utils
ictionries-coon
iffutils
irngr
istro-info
istro-info-t
event
iecoe
setup
z-cursor-thee
nssq-bse
ns-root-t
ocbook-xl
osfstools
pkg
uplicity
e2fsprogs
etyt
e
eject
ecsen-coon
enchnt-2
eog
espek-ng-t
ethtool
evince
evince-coon
evolution-t-server
evolution-t-server-coon
fisk
file
file-roller
finlr
finutils
firefox
fontconfig
fontconfig-config
fonts-beng
fonts-beng-extr
fonts-ejvu-core
fonts-ejvu-extr
fonts-ev
fonts-ev-extr
fonts-roi-fllbck
fonts-freefont-ttf
fonts-grgi
fonts-gubbi
fonts-gujr
fonts-gujr-extr
fonts-guru
fonts-guru-extr
fonts-inic
fonts-kcst
fonts-kcst-one
fonts-klpi
fonts-kheros-core
fonts-kn
fonts-lo
fonts-libertion
fonts-libertion2
fonts-lklug-sinhl
fonts-lohit-beng-ssese
fonts-lohit-beng-bengli
fonts-lohit-ev
fonts-lohit-gujr
fonts-lohit-guru
fonts-lohit-kn
fonts-lohit-ly
fonts-lohit-ory
fonts-lohit-tl
fonts-lohit-tl-clssicl
fonts-lohit-telu
fonts-ly
fonts-nkul
fonts-nvilu
fonts-noto-cjk
fonts-noto-color-eoji
fonts-noto-ono
fonts-opensybol
fonts-ory
fonts-ory-extr
fonts-pgul
fonts-shev
fonts-syk-ev
fonts-syk-gujr
fonts-syk-ly
fonts-syk-tl
fonts-sri
fonts-sil-byssinic
fonts-sil-puk
fonts-sc
fonts-sc-njliollipi
fonts-sc-chilnk
fonts-sc-yuthi
fonts-sc-gythri
fonts-sc-krubi
fonts-sc-kerleey
fonts-sc-njri
fonts-sc-eer
fonts-sc-rchn
fonts-sc-rghulylsns
fonts-sc-suru
fonts-sc-uroob
fonts-tl
fonts-telu
fonts-telu-extr
fonts-thi-tlwg
fonts-tibetn-chine
fonts-tlwg-gru
fonts-tlwg-gru-ttf
fonts-tlwg-kinnri
fonts-tlwg-kinnri-ttf
fonts-tlwg-lksn
fonts-tlwg-lksn-ttf
fonts-tlwg-lo
fonts-tlwg-lo-ttf
fonts-tlwg-ono
fonts-tlwg-ono-ttf
fonts-tlwg-norsi
fonts-tlwg-norsi-ttf
fonts-tlwg-puris
fonts-tlwg-puris-ttf
fonts-tlwg-swsee
fonts-tlwg-swsee-ttf
fonts-tlwg-typewriter
fonts-tlwg-typewriter-ttf
fonts-tlwg-typist
fonts-tlwg-typist-ttf
fonts-tlwg-typo
fonts-tlwg-typo-ttf
fonts-tlwg-upush
fonts-tlwg-upush-ttf
fonts-tlwg-wree
fonts-tlwg-wree-ttf
fonts-ubuntu
fonts-ubuntu-console
fonts-urw-bse35
fonts-yrs-rs
footic-b-copresse-pps
fprint
frienly-recovery
ftp
fuse
fwup
fwup-signe
geoe
gwk
gcc-10-bse
gcc-9-bse
gcr
gb
gbserver
gisk
g3
geit
geit-coon
genisoige
geoclue-2.0
gettext-bse
ghostscript
ghostscript-x
gir1.2-ccountsservice-1.0
gir1.2-tk-1.0
gir1.2-tspi-2.0
gir1.2-clutter-1.0
gir1.2-clutter-gst-3.0
gir1.2-cogl-1.0
gir1.2-coglpngo-1.0
gir1.2-busenu-glib-0.
gir1.2-ee-1.0
gir1.2-freeesktop
gir1.2-gck-1
gir1.2-gcr-3
gir1.2-gesktopenus-3.0
gir1.2-gkpixbuf-2.0
gir1.2-g-1.0
gir1.2-geoclue-2.0
gir1.2-glib-2.0
gir1.2-genu-3.0
gir1.2-gnoebluetooth-1.0
gir1.2-gnoeesktop-3.0
gir1.2-go-1.0
gir1.2-grphene-1.0
gir1.2-gst-plugins-bse-1.0
gir1.2-gstreer-1.0
gir1.2-gtk-3.0
gir1.2-gtkclutter-1.0
gir1.2-gtksource-
gir1.2-guev-1.0
gir1.2-gwether-3.0
gir1.2-ibus-1.0
gir1.2-jvscriptcoregtk-.0
gir1.2-json-1.0
gir1.2-utter-
gir1.2-n-1.0
gir1.2-n-1.0
gir1.2-notify-0.7
gir1.2-pckgekitglib-1.0
gir1.2-pngo-1.0
gir1.2-pes-1.0
gir1.2-polkit-1.0
gir1.2-rb-3.0
gir1.2-rsvg-2.0
gir1.2-secret-1
gir1.2-snp-1
gir1.2-soup-2.
gir1.2-tote-1.0
gir1.2-toteplprser-1.0
gir1.2-uisks-2.0
gir1.2-unity-5.0
gir1.2-upowerglib-1.0
gir1.2-vte-2.91
gir1.2-webkit2-.0
gir1.2-wnck-3.0
git
git-n
gjs
gkb-cpplet
glib-networking
glib-networking-coon
glib-networking-services
gnoe-ccessibility-thees
gnoe-bluetooth
gnoe-clcultor
gnoe-clenr
gnoe-chrcters
gnoe-control-center
gnoe-control-center-t
gnoe-control-center-fces
gnoe-esktop3-t
gnoe-isk-utility
gnoe-font-viewer
gnoe-getting-strte-ocs
gnoe-initil-setup
gnoe-keyring
gnoe-keyring-pkcs11
gnoe-logs
gnoe-hjongg
gnoe-enus
gnoe-ines
gnoe-online-ccounts
gnoe-power-nger
gnoe-screenshot
gnoe-session-bin
gnoe-session-cnberr
gnoe-session-coon
gnoe-settings-eon
gnoe-settings-eon-coon
gnoe-shell
gnoe-shell-coon
gnoe-shell-extension-ppinictor
gnoe-shell-extension-esktop-icons
gnoe-shell-extension-ubuntu-ock
gnoe-strtup-pplictions
gnoe-suoku
gnoe-syste-onitor
gnoe-terinl
gnoe-terinl-t
gnoe-thees-extr
gnoe-thees-extr-t
gnoe-too
gnoe-too-coon
gnoe-user-ocs
gnoe-vieo-effects
gnupg
gnupg-l10n
gnupg-utils
gpg
gpg-gent
gpgconf
gpgs
gpgv
gpg-wks-client
gpg-wks-server
grep
grilo-plugins-0.3-bse
groff-bse
grub2-coon
grub-coon
grub-gfxpylo-lists
grub-pc
grub-pc-bin
gsettings-esktop-sches
gsettings-ubuntu-sches
gstreer1.0-ls
gstreer1.0-clutter-3.0
gstreer1.0-gl
gstreer1.0-gtk3
gstreer1.0-pckgekit
gstreer1.0-plugins-bse
gstreer1.0-plugins-bse-pps
gstreer1.0-plugins-goo
gstreer1.0-pulseuio
gstreer1.0-tools
gstreer1.0-x
gtk2-engines-urrine
gtk2-engines-pixbuf
gtk-upte-icon-cche
guile-2.2-libs
gvfs
gvfs-bckens
gvfs-bin
gvfs-coon
gvfs-eons
gvfs-fuse
gvfs-libs
gzip
hpr
hicolor-icon-thee
hostne
hplip
hplip-t
htop
hunity-icon-thee
hunspell-en-us
ibus
ibus-t
ibus-gtk3
ibus-gtk
ibus-tble
ibverbs-proviers
iio-sensor-proxy
i-config
info
init
initrfs-tools
initrfs-tools-bin
initrfs-tools-core
init-syste-helpers
inputttch
instll-info
intel-icrocoe
ippusbx
iproute2
iptbles
iputils-ping
iputils-trcepth
irqblnce
isc-hcp-client
isc-hcp-coon
iso-coes
iucoe-tool
iw
jv-coon
kb
kerneloops
keybor-configurtion
klibc-utils
ko
kprtx
krb5-locles
lnscpe-coon
lnguge-selector-coon
lnguge-selector-gnoe
lptop-etect
less
lib1
libbw-0.1-1
libccountsservice0
libcl1
libio1
libtk-5-0
libtk-5-coon
libo
libo-coon
libppror1
libppinictor3-1
libppstre
libpr1
libprutil1
libprutil1-b-sqlite3
libprutil1-lp
libpt-pkg.0
librchive13
librgon2-1
libsn1-8-heil
libsoun2
libsoun2-t
libsoun2-plugins
libspell15
libssun0
libsyncns0
libtsrt
libtk1.0-0
libtk1.0-t
libtk-ptor
libtk-brige2.0-0
libtk-1.-1v5
libtk-wrpper-jv
libtk-wrpper-jv-jni
libt1
libtopology2
libtspi2.0-0
libttr1
libuit1
libuit-coon
libuthen-ssl-perl
libvhi-client3
libvhi-coon3
libvhi-coon-t
libvhi-core7
libvhi-glib1
libvhi-ui-gtk3-0
libvc139-0
libbbeltrce1
libblki1
libblockev2
libblockev-crypto2
libblockev-fs2
libblockev-loop2
libblockev-prt2
libblockev-prt-err2
libblockev-swp2
libblockev-utils2
libbluetooth3
libboost-te-tie1.71.0
libboost-filesyste1.71.0
libboost-iostres1.71.0
libboost-locle1.71.0
libboost-thre1.71.0
libbrlpi0.7
libbrotli1
libbs0
libbz2-1.0
libc
libc-bg
libcc0
libciro2
libciro-gobject2
libciro-gobject-perl
libciro-1.0-1v5
libciro-perl
libcel-1.2-2
libcnberr0
libcnberr-gtk3-0
libcnberr-gtk3-oule
libcnberr-pulse
libcp2
libcp2-bin
libcp-ng0
libc-bin
libcbor0.
libcc1-0
libcio18
libcio-c2
libcio-prnoi2
libcprnoi0
libcr-0.1-1
libcephfs2
libcgi-fst-perl
libcgi-p-perl
libcheese8
libcheese-gtk25
libclucene-contribs1v5
libclucene-core1v5
libclutter-1.0-0
libclutter-1.0-coon
libclutter-gst-3.0-0
libclutter-gtk-1.0-0
libcis-0.5-5v5
libcogl20
libcogl-coon
libcogl-pngo20
libcogl-pth20
libcol2
libcolor2
libcolor-gtk1
libcolorhug2
libco-err2
libcrck2
libcrypt1
libcryptsetup12
libcue2
libcups2
libcupsfilters1
libcupsige2
libcurl3-gnutls
libcurl
libeon0
libt-up-perl
libtrie1
libzzle-1.0-0
libb5.3
libbus-1-3
libbus-glib-1-2
libbusenu-glib
libbusenu-gtk3-
libconf1
libebconfclient0
libee-1.0-
libevpper1.02.1
libevpper-event1.02.1
libjvulibre21
libjvulibre-text
libpshring-3.0-2
libns-export1109
libotconf0
libpkg-perl
libr2
libr-gpu1
libr-coon
libr-intel1
libr-nouveu2
libr-reon1
libv
libw1
libetyt1
libebcken-1.2-10
libe-book-0.1-1
libebook-1.2-20
libebook-contcts-1.2-3
libecl-2.0-1
libet-book-1.2-2
libet-cl-2.0-1
libetserver-1.2-2
libetserverui-1.2-2
libeit2
libefiboot1
libefivr1
libegl1
libegl-es0
libelf1
libenchnt-2-2
libencoe-locle-perl
libeot0
libepoxy0
libepubgen-0.1-1
liberror-perl
libespek-ng1
libestr0
libetonyek-0.1-1
libevev2
libevocuent3-
libevent-2.1-7
libevent-core-2.1-7
libevent-pthres-2.1-7
libevview3-3
libexepi8
libexif12
libexiv2-27
libexpt1
libext2fs2
libexttextct-2.0-0
libexttextct-t
libextutils-epens-perl
libextutils-pkgconfig-perl
libfstjson
libfcgi-perl
libfisk1
libffi7
libfftw3-single3
libfio2-1
libfile-bseir-perl
libfile-esktopentry-perl
libfile-fcntllock-perl
libfile-listing-perl
libfile-ieinfo-perl
libfl2
libflc8
libfont-f-perl
libfontconfig1
libfontebe1
libfontenc1
libfprint-2-2
libfprint-2-to1
libfreehn-0.1-1
libfreerp2-2
libfreerp-client2-2
libfreetype
libfribii0
libfuse2
libfwup2
libfwupplugin1
libgil18
libgil-coon
libgeoe0
libgeoeuto0
libgb1
libgc1c2
libgcb-1.0-0
libgcc-s1
libgck-1-0
libgcr-bse-3-1
libgcr-ui-3-1
libgcrypt20
libg3
libgt22
libgt-coon
libgb
libgb-copt
libgk-pixbuf2.0-0
libgk-pixbuf2.0-bin
libgk-pixbuf2.0-coon
libg1
libgee-0.8-2
libgeoclue-2-0
libgeocoe-glib0
libgexiv2-2
libgif7
libgirepository-1.0-1
libgjs0g
libgl1
libgl1-es-ri
libgl1-es-glx
libglpi-es
libgles2
libglib2.0-0
libglib2.0-bin
libglib2.0-t
libglib-2.-1v5
libglib-object-introspection-perl
libglib-perl
libglu1-es
libglvn0
libglx0
libglx-es0
libgp10
libgnoe-utor-0-0
libgnoe-bluetooth13
libgnoe-esktop-3-19
libgnoe-ges-support-1-3
libgnoe-ges-support-coon
libgnoekb8
libgnoekb-coon
libgnoe-enu-3-0
libgnoe-too
libgnutls30
libgo-1.0-0b
libgo-1.0-coon
libgo-bcken-1.0-1
libgo-1.0-0
libgop1
libgpg-error0
libgpge11
libgpgepp
libgphoto2-
libgphoto2-l10n
libgphoto2-port12
libgp2
libgpo
libgpo-coon
libgrphene-1.0-0
libgrphite2-3
libgrilo-0.3-0
libgs9
libgs9-coon
libgsf-1-11
libgsf-1-coon
libgsoun0
libgspell-1-2
libgspell-1-coon
libgsspi3-heil
libgsspi-krb5-2
libgssp-1.2-0
libgstreer1.0-0
libgstreer-gl1.0-0
libgstreer-plugins-bse1.0-0
libgstreer-plugins-goo1.0-0
libgtk2.0-0
libgtk2.0-bin
libgtk2.0-coon
libgtk-3-0
libgtk-3-bin
libgtk-3-coon
libgtk3-perl
libgtk-3.0-1v5
libgtksourceview--0
libgtksourceview--coon
libgtop-2.0-11
libgtop2-coon
libguev-1.0-0
libgupnp-1.2-0
libgupnp-v-1.0-2
libgupnp-ln-2.0-3
libgusb2
libgwether-3-1
libgwether-coon
libgxps2
libhny-0.0-0
libhrfbuzz0b
libhrfbuzz-icu0
libhcrypto-heil
libheibse1-heil
libheintl0-heil
libhogwee5
libhpu0
libhtl-fort-perl
libhtl-for-perl
libhtl-prser-perl
libhtl-tgset-perl
libhtl-teplte-perl
libhtl-tree-perl
libhttp-cookies-perl
libhttp-eon-perl
libhttp-te-perl
libhttp-essge-perl
libhttp-negotite-perl
libhunspell-1.7-0
libhx509-5-heil
libhyphen0
libibus-1.0-5
libibverbs1
libicl3
libice
libice-ev
libicu
libin11
libin2-0
libiec1883-0
libieee128-3
libijs-0.35
libigequnt0
libiobileevice
libinput10
libinput-bin
libio-htl-perl
libio-socket-ssl-perl
libio-stringy-perl
libiptc2
libiptc2
libipc-syste-siple-perl
libisc-export1105
libisl22
libisns0
libiw30
libjck-jck2-0
libjnsson
libjvscriptcoregtk-.0-18
libjbig0
libjbig2ec0
libjct1
libjpeg8
libjpeg-turbo8
libjson-c
libjson-glib-1.0-0
libjson-glib-1.0-coon
libjuh-jv
libjurt-jv
libk5crypto3
libkeyutils1
libklibc
libko2
libkpthse
libkrb5-2-heil
libkrb5-3
libkrb5support0
libksb8
liblngtg1
liblngtg-coon
liblcs2-2
liblcs2-utils
liblp-2.-2
liblp-coon
liblb2
liblirc-client0
libllv12
libllv9
liblb0
liblocle-gettext-perl
liblouis20
liblouis-t
liblouisutl9
liblouisutl-bin
liblouisutl-t
libltl7
liblu5.2-0
liblu5.3-0
liblv2c2.03
liblwp-eitypes-perl
liblwp-protocol-https-perl
liblz-1
liblz5
liblzo2-2
libgic1
libgic-gc
libiltools-perl
libxinb0
libbi-glib
libbi-proxy
libecb2
libeirt-2.0-0
libessging-enu0
libhsh2
libiniupnpc17
lib-glib0
libnl0
libount1
libozjs-8-0
libp3le0
libpc3
libpec2
libpfr
libpg123-0
libspck0
libspub-0.1-1
libtev1
libtp9
libtp-coon
libtp-runtie
libutter--0
libww-0.3-3
libysqlclient21
libythes-1.2-0
libntpp1
libnutilus-extension1
libncurses
libncursesw
libnp0
libneon27-gnutls
libnet-bus-perl
libnetfilter-conntrck3
libnet-http-perl
libnetpln0
libnet-stp-ssl-perl
libnet-ssley-perl
libnettle7
libnewt0.52
libnfnetlink0
libnfs13
libnftnl11
libnghttp2-1
libnl-3-200
libnl-genl-3-200
libnl-route-3-200
libn0
libn0
libnotify
libnotify-bin
libnpth0
libnspr
libnss3
libnss-ns
libnss-syste
libntfs-3g883
libnu1
libofgen-0.1-1
libogg0
libopenjp2-7
libopus0
liborc-0.-0
liborcus-0.15-0
libp11-kit0
libpckgekit-glib2-18
libpgeker-0.0-0
libp0g
libp-cp
libp-fprint
libp-gnoe-keyring
libp-oules
libp-oules-bin
libp-runtie
libp-syste
libpngo-1.0-0
libpngociro-1.0-0
libpngoft2-1.0-0
libpngo-1.-1v5
libpngoxft-1.0-0
libpper1
libpper-utils
libprte2
libprte-fs-resize0
libpcp0.8
libpcuio0
libpci3
libpciccess0
libpcre2-32-0
libpcre2-8-0
libpcre3
libpcsclite1
libpes-1.0-0
libpes-coon
libperl5.30
libphonenuber7
libpipeline1
libpixn-1-0
libpkcs11-helper1
libplist3
libplyouth5
libpng1-1
libpolkit-gent-1-0
libpolkit-gobject-1-0
libpoppler97
libpoppler-cpp0v5
libpoppler-glib8
libpopt0
libprocps8
libprotobuf17
libproxy1-plugin-gsettings
libproxy1-plugin-networknger
libproxy1v5
libpsl5
libpthre-stubs0-ev
libpulse0
libpulsesp
libpulse-inloop-glib0
libpwqulity1
libpwqulity-coon
libpython3.8
libpython3.8-inil
libpython3.8-stlib
libpython3-stlib
libqi-glib5
libqi-proxy
libqpf2
libqqwing2v5
libros2
librptor2-0
librsql3
librw139-11
librw19
librf0
librc1
libreline5
libreline8
libreoffice-bse-core
libreoffice-clc
libreoffice-coon
libreoffice-core
libreoffice-rw
libreoffice-gnoe
libreoffice-gtk3
libreoffice-ipress
libreoffice-th
libreoffice-ogltrns
libreoffice-pfiport
libreoffice-style-breeze
libreoffice-style-colibre
libreoffice-style-eleentry
libreoffice-style-tngo
libreoffice-writer
librest-0.7-0
librevenge-0.0-0
librhythbox-core10
libril-jv
libroken18-heil
librsvg2-2
librsvg2-coon
librsync2
librtp1
librygel-core-2.-2
librygel-b-2.-2
librygel-renerer-2.-2
librygel-server-2.-2
libsplerte0
libsne
libsne-coon
libsne-hpio
libssl2-2
libssl2-oules
libssl2-oules-b
libsbc1
libseccop2
libsecret-1-0
libsecret-coon
libselinux1
libsenge1
libsenge-coon
libsensors5
libsensors-config
libsepol1
libsgutils2-2
libshout3
libsigc++-2.0-0v5
libsigsegv2
libslng2
libs
libsrtcols1
libsbclient
libsbios-c2
libs-ev
libsnp-glib1
libsnfile1
libsnp35
libsnp-bse
libsoiu23
libsonic0
libsoup2.-1
libsoup-gnoe2.-1
libsoxr0
libspectre1
libspeech2
libspeex1
libspeexsp1
libsqlite3-0
libss2
libssh-
libssl1.1
libstrtup-notifiction0
libstc++
libsteer0
libsuitesprseconfig5
libsynctex2
libsysetrics1
libsyste0
libtg1v5
libtg1v5-vnill
libtlloc2
libtsn1-
libtb1
libtectl0
libtepl--0
libtevent0
libtext-chrwith-perl
libtext-iconv-perl
libtext-wrpi18n-perl
libthi0
libthi-t
libtheor0
libtie-ixhsh-perl
libtiff5
libtiete-perl
libtinfo
libtote0
libtote-plprser18
libtote-plprser-coon
libtrcker-control-2.0-0
libtrcker-iner-2.0-0
libtrcker-sprql-2.0-0
libtry-tiny-perl
libtss2-esys0
libtwole0
libu2f-uev
libuchret0
libuev1
libuisks2-0
libunistring2
libunity9
libunity-protocol-privte0
libunity-scopes-json-ef-esktop
libuno-cppu3
libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3
libunoloer-jv
libuno-purpenvhelpergcc3-3
libuno-sl3
libuno-slhelpergcc3-3
libunwin8
libupower-glib3
liburcu
liburi-perl
libusb-1.0-0
libusbux
libutepter0
libuui1
libuv1
libvl-0
libvlconvert0
libvisio-0.1-1
libvisul-0.-0
libvncclient1
libvolue-key1
libvorbis0
libvorbisenc2
libvorbisfile3
libvpx
libvte-2.91-0
libvte-2.91-coon
libvulkn1
libwco2
libwco-bin
libwco-coon
libwvpck1
libwyln-client0
libwyln-cursor0
libwyln-egl1
libwyln-server0
libwbclient0
libwebkit2gtk-.0-37
libwebp
libwebpeux2
libwebpux3
libwebrtc-uio-processing1
libwhoopsie0
libwhoopsie-preferences0
libwin0-heil
libwinpr2-2
libwf0.2-7
libwf0.2-7-gtk
libwnck-3-0
libwnck-3-coon
libwoff1
libwp-0.10-10
libwpg-0.3-3
libwps-0.-
libwrp0
libwww-perl
libwww-robotrules-perl
libx11-
libx11-t
libx11-ev
libx11-protocol-perl
libx11-xcb1
libxtrcker2
libxu
libxu-ev
libxw7
libxcb1
libxcb1-ev
libxcb-ri2-0
libxcb-ri3-0
libxcb-glx0
libxcb-iccc
libxcb-ige0
libxcb-keysys1
libxcb-present0
libxcb-rnr0
libxcb-rener0
libxcb-rener-util0
libxcb-res0
libxcb-shpe0
libxcb-sh0
libxcb-sync1
libxcb-util1
libxcb-xfixes0
libxcb-xkb1
libxcb-xv0
libxcoposite1
libxcursor1
libxge1
libxcp
libxcp-ev
libxext
libxfixes3
libxfont2
libxft2
libxi
libxiner1
libxkbcoon0
libxkbcoon-x11-0
libxkbfile1
libxklvier1
libxl2
libxlb1
libxl-prser-perl
libxlsec1
libxlsec1-nss
libxlsec1-openssl
libxl-twig-perl
libxl-xpthengine-perl
libxu
libxuu1
libxp
libxrnr2
libxrener1
libxres1
libxshfence1
libxslt1.1
libxss1
libxt
libxtbles12
libxt-ev
libxtst
libxv1
libxvc1
libxxf8g1
libxxf8v1
libyjl2
libyl-0-2
libyelp0
libzst1
linux-bse
linux-firwre
linux-generic
linux-heers-5..0-100
linux-heers-5..0-100-generic
linux-heers-5..0-99
linux-heers-5..0-99-generic
linux-heers-generic
linux-ige-5..0-100-generic
linux-ige-5..0-99-generic
linux-ige-generic
linux-oules-5..0-100-generic
linux-oules-5..0-99-generic
linux-oules-extr-5..0-100-generic
linux-oules-extr-5..0-99-generic
linux-soun-bse
locles
login
logrotte
logsve
lp-solve
lsb-bse
lsb-relese
lshw
lsof
ltrce
lv2
lx-gent-loer
lz
n-b
npges
wk

ecb-ipic
ecb-ipic-utf8
ecb-utils
ei-plyer-info
etest8+
es-vulkn-rivers
ie-support
obile-brobn-provier-info
oenger
ot-news-config
ount
ousetweks
scopress
tools
tr-tiny
ultipth-tools
utter
utter-coon
ysql-client-8.0
ysql-client-core-8.0
ysql-coon
ysql-server
ysql-server-8.0
ysql-server-core-8.0
nno
nutilus
nutilus-t
nutilus-extension-gnoe-terinl
nutilus-sento
nutilus-shre
ncurses-bse
ncurses-bin
ncurses-ter
netbse
netct-openbs
netpln.io
net-tools
network-isptcher
network-nger
network-nger-config-connectivity-ubuntu
network-nger-gnoe
network-nger-openvpn
network-nger-openvpn-gnoe
network-nger-pptp
network-nger-pptp-gnoe
ntfs-3g
open-iscsi
openjk-8-jk
openjk-8-jk-heless
openjk-8-jre
openjk-8-jre-heless
openprinting-pps
openssh-client
openssh-server
openssh-sftp-server
openssl
open-v-tools
openvpn
orc
os-prober
overlyroot
p11-kit
p11-kit-oules
pckgekit
pckgekit-tools
prte
pssw
pstebinit
ptch
pci.is
pciutils
pcciutils
perl
perl-bse
perl-oules-5.30
perl-openssl-efults
pinentry-curses
pinentry-gnoe3
pkg-config
plyouth
plyouth-lbel
plyouth-thee-spinner
plyouth-thee-ubuntu-text
policykit-1
policykit-esktop-privileges
pollinte
poppler-t
poppler-utils
populrity-contest
powergt-bse
ppp
pptp-linux
printer-river-brlser
printer-river-c2esp
printer-river-foo2zjs
printer-river-foo2zjs-coon
printer-river-hpcups
printer-river-2300w
printer-river-in12xxw
printer-river-pn2pp
printer-river-postscript-hp
printer-river-ptouch
printer-river-pxljr
printer-river-sg-gi
printer-river-splix
procps
psisc
publicsuffix
pulseuio
pulseuio-oule-bluetooth
pulseuio-utils
python3
python3.8
python3.8-inil
python3-pport
python3-pt
python3-pteon
python3-pteon.gtk3wigets
python3-ttr
python3-utot
python3-bcrypt
python3-blinker
python3-brlpi
python3-ciro
python3-certifi
python3-cffi-bcken
python3-chret
python3-click
python3-color
python3-connotfoun
python3-configobj
python3-constntly
python3-crypto
python3-cryptogrphy
python3-cups
python3-cupshelpers
python3-teutil
python3-bus
python3-ebconf
python3-ebin
python3-efer
python3-istro
python3-istro-info
python3-istupgre
python3-istutils
python3-nspython
python3-entrypoints
python3-fsteners
python3-future
python3-gb
python3-gi
python3-gi-ciro
python3-gpg
python3-hcrest
python3-httplib2
python3-hyperlink
python3-ibus-1.0
python3-in
python3-iportlib-ett
python3-increentl
python3-jinj2
python3-jsonptch
python3-json-pointer
python3-jsonsche
python3-jwt
python3-keyring
python3-lunchplib
python3-lzr.restfulclient
python3-lzr.uri
python3-lb
python3-lib2to3
python3-lockfile
python3-louis
python3-croonbkery
python3-ko
python3-rkown
python3-rkupsfe
python3-inil
python3-onotonic
python3-ore-itertools
python3-ncl
python3-netifces
python3-newt
python3-outhlib
python3-olefile
python3-openssl
python3-pckging
python3-priko
python3-pexpect
python3-pil
python3-pkg-resources
python3-proble-report
python3-protobuf
python3-ptyprocess
python3-pysn1
python3-pysn1-oules
python3-pytspi
python3-pygents
python3-pycroons
python3-pyprsing
python3-pyrsistent
python3-renerp
python3-reportlb
python3-reportlb-ccel
python3-requests
python3-requests-unixsocket
python3-rfc3339
python3-sb
python3-secretstorge
python3-seril
python3-service-ientity
python3-setuptools
python3-siplejson
python3-six
python3-softwre-properties
python3-speech
python3-syste
python3-tlloc
python3-tb
python3-twiste
python3-twiste-bin
python3-tz
python3-uno
python3-upte-nger
python3-urllib3
python3-wllib
python3-xg
python3-xkit
python3-yl
python3-zipp
python3-zope.interfce
python-pt-coon
reline-coon
rein
rein-coon
rein-plugin-rp
rein-plugin-secret
rein-plugin-vnc
rfkill
rhythbox
rhythbox-t
rhythbox-plugin-lterntive-toolbr
rhythbox-plugins
rsync
rsyslog
rtkit
run-one
rygel
sb
sb-coon
sb-coon-bin
sb-sb-oules
sb-libs
sb-vfs-oules
sne-utils
sbsigntool
screen
sehorse
secureboot-b
se
sensible-utils
session-igrtion
sg3-utils
sg3-utils-uev
sgl-bse
sgl-t
shre-ie-info
shotwell
shotwell-coon
siple-scn
sbclient
snp
softwre-properties-coon
softwre-properties-gtk
sosreport
soun-icons
soun-thee-freeesktop
speech-isptcher
speech-isptcher-uio-plugins
speech-isptcher-espek-ng
spice-vgent
squshfs-tools
ssh-iport-i
ssl-cert
strce
suo
switcheroo-control
syslinux
syslinux-coon
syslinux-legcy
syste-config-printer
syste-config-printer-coon
syste-config-printer-uev
syste
syste-sysv
syste-tiesync
sysvinit-utils
tr
tsksel
tsksel-t
tcpup
tb-tools
telnet
therl
thin-provisioning-tools
thunerbir
thunerbir-gnoe-support
tie
tux
tote
tote-coon
tote-plugins
tp-uev
trcker
trcker-extrct
trcker-iner-fs
trnsission-coon
trnsission-gtk
tzt
ubuntu-vntge-tools
ubuntu-esktop
ubuntu-esktop-inil
ubuntu-ocs
ubuntu-rivers-coon
ubuntu-keyring
ubuntu-inil
ubuntu-ono
ubuntu-relese-upgrer-core
ubuntu-relese-upgrer-gtk
ubuntu-report
ubuntu-server
ubuntu-session
ubuntu-settings
ubuntu-stnr
ubuntu-wllppers
ubuntu-wllppers-focl
ucf
uev
uisks2
ufw
unttene-upgres
uno-libs-privte
unzip
upte-inet
upte-nger
upte-nger-core
upte-notifier
upte-notifier-coon
upower
ure
usb-cretor-coon
usb-cretor-gtk
usb.is
usb-oeswitch
usb-oeswitch-t
usbux
usbutils
util-linux
uui-runtie
/vr/lib/pkg/info/fort-new
/vr/lib/pkg/sttus
vi
vi-coon
vi-runtie
vi-tiny
vino
wericn
wget
whiptil
whoopsie
whoopsie-preferences
wireless-regb
wireless-tools
wpsupplicnt
x11-pps
x11-coon
x11proto-core-ev
x11proto-ev
x11-session-utils
x11-utils
x11-xkb-utils
x11-xserver-utils
xuth
xbitps
xbrlpi
xcursor-thees
xg-bus-proxy
xg-esktop-portl
xg-esktop-portl-gtk
xg-user-irs
xg-user-irs-gtk
xg-utils
xfonts-bse
xfonts-encoings
xfonts-sclble
xfonts-utils
xfsprogs
xinit
xinput
xkb-t
xl-core
xorg
xorg-ocs-core
xorg-sgl-octools
xserver-coon
xserver-xephyr
xserver-xorg
xserver-xorg-core
xserver-xorg-input-ll
xserver-xorg-input-libinput
xserver-xorg-input-wco
xserver-xorg-legcy
xserver-xorg-vieo-ll
xserver-xorg-vieo-gpu
xserver-xorg-vieo-ti
xserver-xorg-vieo-fbev
xserver-xorg-vieo-intel
xserver-xorg-vieo-nouveu
xserver-xorg-vieo-qxl
xserver-xorg-vieo-reon
xserver-xorg-vieo-ves
xserver-xorg-vieo-vwre
xtrns-ev
xul-ext-ubufox
xwyln
xx
xz-utils
yru-thee-gnoe-shell
yru-thee-gtk
yru-thee-icon
yru-thee-soun
yelp
yelp-xsl
zenity
zenity-coon
zerofree
zip
zlib1g
```

I got it by piping the following commands:

```bsh
$ touch base
$ touch clean
$ sudo cat /var/log/apt/term.log > base
$ grep dpkg: base | grep -Po "[^'\n ]+'" | tr -d '`' | tr -d "'" | tr -d ":amd64" | sort -u > clean
```

EDIT 3:

I've been purging a lot of packages after finding out that someone did try to install a DE. While a found a lot of head-scracthers checking packages, I finally understand that the errors source come from the fact that there are a lot of missing files in the `/var/lib/dpkg/info` directory. Every file reported in the logs I fetched are not in said directory, and those that I reinstalled while purging the GUI packages have `list` and `.md5sums` files (At least). I guess that now the real question is how to "rebuild" this directory, given that the server is working as expected so far.

Comment: Don't summarize or describe the input and output. Show us actual input and output. The detail that you are summarizing away is the detail we need to see.

Comment: I'm sorry, if you refer to the list of files/packages, I didn't add it because it has 1700+ lines. I'm not sure what's the best way to post a file that long. I will just paste it.

Comment: Time to re install from scratch. With the things you have been doing, the little described you have quite a mess.

Comment: I actually managed to "save" it. I will post the answer to this particular problem (Since that solution led me to another whole topic that took half day to solve), but I will re install if there is any weird behavior again.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr:** Reinstall whatever packages throw a warning. For an "automated" way to do things, see commands below.

I managed to fix the issue about the warnings. This resulted in a number of different problems like missing libraries and failures to install other packages like grub and python. I believe this is due to my particular circumstances about removing all I could that is related to a GUI, but is important to mention it.

The source of the warnings is the missing files under `/var/lib/dpkg/info`. I confirmed this by reinstalling something and checking whether or not any file related to the package appeared in this directory. Files were created and the warnings now didn't include the reinstalled package, so that's the solution **for the warnings**.

I ran the following to fetch a list of the packages reported in the logs:

```bsh
$ touch base
$ touch clean
$ sudo cat /var/log/apt/term.log > base
$ cat base | grep "dpkg: <<message of the problem in the SO's language>>" | grep -Po "[^'\n ]+'" | tr -d '`' | tr -d "'" | cut -f1 -d":" | sort -u > clean
```

Because I wanted to check more things in the log, I kept `base`. If you have no use to a copy of the log, pipe directly from `/var/log/apt/term.log/`.

Also, I recommend checking the list in clean and deleting any package you know you don't have (ie, you uninstalled that package anyway, so the warning is meaningless now). I did this as well since packages from gnome where included in this list and I didn't want installed again.

To reinstall the packages, I used this small script

```bsh
for package in $(cat $1) ; do
    apt install --reinstall $package
done
```

calling it like `sudo ./script.sh clean`. This can be optimized a lot, but it is as good as I can do right now.

This will take time since it's doing the `apt install` one by one (For the machine where this happened, it took over 3 hours). After it's done, different problems might arise.

Also, I would only recommend this if the number of packages is small. In my case, I cleaned over 300 packages from the list, but still had to install a lot. I also only attempted to "fix" this since I have no information in this machine and I have no problems reinstalling the whole SO again. If you run this in a machine with **important information, back it up**.

Comment: use `sudo apt-get install --reinstall $(grep -vE "^\s*#" ./clean | tr "\n" " ")` to reinstall packages